# Is there an approach to stretch out the width cc on youtube?

Tags: youtube

I am learning this Machine learning video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qgjZtcfdp0E&list=PLuyk1nLMhRm4gngmWSvSkIjn1VLUQnxid)

[image]

Is there an approach to stretch out the cc to the red vertical bars?

None of the option is to adjust the width of the cc box.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fix YouTube captions that have abnormally low-contrast](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/103543/fix-youtube-captions-that-have-abnormally-low-contrast)

Comment: @Kos None of the option is to adjust the width of the cc box.